# Deploying PHP application using AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am very new to AWS. I am trying to deploy my php application to AWS. I created an environment and then uploaded and deployed all files (including .sql) in zip format. When I am trying to access my website using URL it doesn't show anything. When I tried viewing page source, it showed database connectivity error?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: BeansTalk won't import you SQL files into a database. And it won't setup database credentials (but you can use environment variables for that, I guess). That's your responsibility.

Comment: @SergeyKovalev I have created RDS which is connected with my Beanstalk environment. Could you just guide me to import my sql file and connect sql file to my PHP files. That would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

For Database connection, 
You need create a new environment either using RDS or on the instance.

You can set up RDS using Beanstalk.

Refer :http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP.rds.html#create_deploy_PHP.rds.newDB

Still you will have much to manually configure to load your existing data to RDS or to the instance.

Hope it Helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had written a blog on a similar use case. I also have a screencast on the same. Can you follow this and see if this helps:

http://www.tothenew.com/blog/aws-elastic-beanstalk-php/

I have deployed a wordpress PHP website. Look what you need is a new RDS or an old RDS instance or Database on an EC2 server and have to give PHP app that endpoint and port.